# Why do Friedman and Wilcoxon post-hoc contradict each other for my data?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, interpretation, post-hoc

I conducted an experiment, testing three conditions with 27 participants in a repeated measures design. Since the data is not normally distributed I used a Friedman test that reported a p-value of 0.1, a slight disappointment given how much time I spent in the lab. Being disappointed but curious, I still performed Wilcoxon's signed rank test as post-hoc analyses for the three pairs. The interesting thing is that these tests reported p-values 0.002, 0.004 and 0.25, respectively. Even after a - conservative - Bonferroni correction two of the p's are still significant.

Now, besides the ethical/scientific issues surrounding digging around in the data like that: why are the p-values of the Friedman and the Wilcoxon tests so far apart? And: how do I interpret these findings? They seem to contradict each other.

Comment: You have repeated measures, but neither Friedman nor Wilcoxon pays any attention to the structure implied. The main answer to your post is that different questions get different answers; that is not a contradiction.

Comment: The same kind of thing can happen with other post-hoc tests.

Comment: Note that the Friedman test in most situations has far less power than Wilcoxon-type tests.  A generalization of the Wilcoxon test that is more suited to your situation is the mixed effects proportional odds model.  But a quick and only slightly dirty approach is to use multiple Wilcoxon tests as you have done.  On a more general note, even if the best available method resulted in a large P-value, the time was not wasted in the lab; it's just that many people are biased against "negative" studies.  It is possible to learn a great deal from negative studies.

Comment: 1) In Friedman, you rank within all 3 conditions at once, but in pairwise comparisons you rank only within 2 being currently compared. So the results need not to agree. 2) Even more: Friedman test is _not_ the extension of Wilcoxon test over to 3+ conditions. Friedman is - I'd say - closer to be an "extended" sign z-test.

Comment: @NickCox what do you mean by "the structure"?

Comment: @FrankHarrell thanks for the kind words. The problem is not that I want to publish the results. I know that publishing negative results is indeed a good thing (publication bias). The problem is that I wanted to know if there is a difference since I wanted to use that knowledge for a subsequent study.

Comment: The structure of the data (e.g. what is dependent, what is independent) as reflecting the data generating process.

Comment: @NickCox I see. In R, though, I have to state explicitly the blocks and groups (e.g. using model formulae like "measure ~ variant | participant"). Doesn't that indicate that the structure is used? Or am I misunderstanding what you mean?

Comment: I don't use R to comment authoritatively, but the issues are pretty much the same with any software. If you use something intended for repeated measures, you should get what you ask for. The issue is whether Friedman or Wilcoxon routines know that they are dealing with repeated measures when they are. You would have to spell your design and consult the documentation, but usually this is not well explained at all.

Comment: @xmjx be sure not to make the "absence of evidence is not evidence for absence" mistake.  You would need to base you "if there is a difference" assessment on confidence intervals excluding meaningful differences, not on large P-values.

Comment: As far as i know, you can't run Wilcoxon reliably, if Friedman test showed no significant difference.